# Changing text in div with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<div>Text: <a href="#">Fly London</a></div>
```

I want to change the text "Text:" with JS, so I used this:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('.p-detail-info > div:contains("Text:")').text('Another text:');
     });
</script>
```

But if I do it, the URL will disappear. How to change it if I want to keep URL?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd add jQuery as a tag to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by simply add span tag and change the span tag text

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.p-detail-info > div > span:contains("Text:")').text('Another text:');});
```

```html
   





 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="p-detail-info">
<div><span>Text:</span> <a href="#">Fly London</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to select the *text node*, which is not possible with selectors alone, unfortunately. Select the parent `div`, get its first `childNode` (which is the text node we want), and then assign to the text node's `textContent`, no jQuery required:

```js
document.querySelector('div').childNodes[0].textContent = 'Another Text';
```

```html
<div>Text: <a href="#">Fly London</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should work fine for changing the text:

`<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.p-detail-info > div').text('Another text:');});<script>`

Cheers,
Happy coding.